# IV of first 16 bytes gets remove from decrypted string? C#/Python3

Tags: c#, python-3.x, encryption, aes

I was wondering why the first 16 bytes of all my strings being encrypted, then when being decrypted are missing and how to fix this if it is possible. I am encrypting like so in c#

```cs
        public static string EncryptString(string b_key, string plainText)  
        {  
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];  
            byte[] array;  
  
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())  
            {  
                aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(b_key);  
                aes.IV = iv;  
  
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);  
  
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())  
                {  
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))  
                    {  
                        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream)cryptoStream))  
                        {  
                            streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                        }  
  
                        array = memoryStream.ToArray();  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
  
            return Convert.ToBase64String(array);  
        }
```

and decrypting in python3 like so

```py
            enc = base64.b64decode(self.text)
            iv = enc[:16]
            cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
            plain_text = cipher.decrypt(enc[16:])
            plain_text = self.dePKCS7_padding(plain_text)
            return plain_text
```

Is readding the first 16 bytes possible? or must be used for encryption. I also want it to crypto safe but the first 16 bytes are kind of important is this possible? anyway to get around this in either c# or python3?

Comment: Why do you assume on the Python side that the IV is stored in what AES encodes on the C# side (it isn't). Why do you use a blank IV, was that on purpose?

Comment: I thought C# stores it in the AES because of the variable ```iv``` how would i store it in the AES? It just worked tbh if this string was long enough then it worked but now i am working with smaller strings and it is breaking

Comment: You are using AES with **CBC** mode that requires an (randomly) generated initialization vector ("IV"). In your C# implementation you are using a **static** IV ("byte[] iv = new byte[16];" is filled with16 x00's) - this is **UNSECURE** and please do not use it any further. Better create the IV secure randomly and transport it along with the ciphertext to the recipient, whereit is needed for decryption. Usually the IV and ciphertext are concatenated (IV|ciphertext) and for decryption split - therefore the Python code strips off the first 16 bytes and uses them as input for decryption-IV.

Comment: @MichaelFehr How do I concatnate the random IV to the string in C#?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya: to be compliant with the python code your concatenation will fail... python expects [in pseudo code] Base64(aes.IV|array).

Comment: `Aes.Create()` _implicitly_ creates a random IV. Just delete `aes.IV = iv`. Alternatively, you can of course _explicitly_ create a random IV. The IV can simply be written to  `memoryStream` with: `memoryStream.Write(aes.IV)`. You can do this immediately after instantiating the `MemoryStream`. This prepends the IV in front of the ciphertext, as expected by the Python code. Note that _PyCryptodome_ provides a [dedicated module for padding](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html?highlight=padding#crypto-util-padding-module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments and inputs from @MichaelFehr and @user9014097, I came up with the following code.

In this code the `IV` of AES will have random value created when `AES.Create()` is called. And the same will be used in the outcome of the encrypted value.

The decryptString method will capture the `iv` value from the incoming encrypted string and assign it to AES while decrypting the string.

```
    public static string EncryptString(string b_key, string plainText)
    {
        byte[] array;

        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(b_key);

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Adding aes.IV to the stream's start.
                memoryStream.Write(aes.IV);
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                    }
                }
                array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        // The final encrypted outcome will be aes.IV+encryptedtext.
        return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
    }

    public static string DecryptString(string key, string cipherText)
    {
        //input is iv+encrypted text, convert them to byte array.
        byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        // byte array for iv
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];

        // byte array for rest of the cipher text.
        byte[] cipherBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length - 16];

        // copy first 16 bytes from the cipher text to iv.
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, iv, 0, 16);


        // copy rest of the cipher text to the cipher buffer to be decrypted.
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 16, cipherBuffer, 0, buffer.Length - 16);

        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
            aes.IV = iv;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherBuffer))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have following assumption in writing above code.

1. Length of `IV` is 16.
2. Python code (shared above) does not need split the input text based on some specific character. It takes first 16 bytes as `IV` value and rest of the bytes as cipher text.

I was able to encrypt and decrypt values successfully in C# using above methods.

I was not able to decrypt the value in python code as I have little to no idea on how to work with python.

You can test the outcome of above encryption in python to decrypt it. Let me know if it doesn't work as expected.

I hope this will help you solve your issue.

Comment: IMHO `memoryStream.ToArray` should be after `cryptoStream` is flushed / disposed. Though disposing `streamWriter` might be sufficient, I wouldn't want to depend on it.

Comment: thank you for the feedback @JeremyLakeman. I updated the code in the answer.